Crosswalk NHD to NHDPlus
I would like to convert a stream dataset from NHD to NHDPlus HR, but am having trouble finding a way to link a common field. My current NHD stream layer has detailed attributes about conditions, habitat, species, etc. and I would like to transfer this information to the NHDPlus streamlines. In my current dataset, the unique identifier for a stream segment is COMID. In the NHDPlus dataset, the unique identifiers are Permanent_Identifier and NHDPlusID. Is there a crosswalk to link COMID to either Permanent_Identifier or NHDPlusID? Or is there another way to join these two datasets?
